# Can't get area height to increase automatically with content

Tags: css

I'm having trouble with this page:

http://dynamic-storage.co.uk/index2.php

On the right hand side, I can't get the area to expand with the content. I've just put a twitter feed in there and I get a scroll bar.

Can anyone help please?

Many thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it has a height given to it in css...

```
#panelwrap {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 595px; /* remove this or set as auto */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

...remove that and the content will expand.

Answer (score 0):

On `#panelwrap` you are explicitly setting a `height`. Remove that or set it to `auto` (which is the default value of `height`).